# Apache REgex fails with stackOverflowError

Tags: java, regex, apache

I noticed that running the `(^.*\n?)` regular expression on a 1400 characters long string that contains no new lines fails on **StackOverflowError** and I wonder what is the reason and if anyone can point out on the string length limitation.

Thanks

Comment: It's not really a string length limitation, it's that this regex is a [runaway regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: There's absolutely no reasons this pattern gives a catastrophic bracktracking problem: 1) it's anchored, 2) it has no constraint. I think your problem comes from elsewhere (perhaps the fact that it matches any string). Is it the full pattern or only a subpattern?

Comment: I suspect it is a part of some other longer pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte this is the full pattern. I noted that when I am using Apache engine I get the StackOverflowError while on other engines it works fine. I really don't know what the problem is...

Comment: @Guy: if the pattern comes from an apache rewrite rule, try to remove the first slash at the beginning in the replacement string if any. If it doesn't work, change your pattern in a way that it doesn't match the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that the below code in Java doesn't give a problem with 10^5 chars.
The regex doesn't seem weird to me. Guy, can you give us more context to what you're trying to accomplish?

```
    package stackOverflowJava;

    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class interactiveProg1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^.*\n?)");
            StringBuffer subject = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
                subject.append("a");
            }
            System.out.println("Subject        : " + subject);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(subject.toString());
            boolean b = m.matches();
            System.out.println("Pattern matches: " + b);
        }

    }

Subject        : aaaaaaaaaaaa...
Pattern matches: true
```